# Create fixed number of Points within polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point, point-in-polygon

I have a polygon shapefile containing 50 features. I have another list where those 50 features are listed with how many number of points need to be created within those polygon. Suppose I have a shapefile containing A, B, C, D polygon and an excel file like following

```
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  2  |
+-----+-----+
|  B  |  6  |
+-----+-----+
|  C  |  9  |
+-----+-----+
|  D  |  3  |
+-----+-----+
```

Is there any easiest way to create those number of points within assigned polygon?

Comment: How do you want the Points distributed in the polygons? Random ,a Square grid, a Square grid with random starting Point etc.?

Comment: Random Points...

Comment: Create random points tool designed for this